# Make searchbar works

Tags: visual-studio, ionic-framework, native, searchbar

how can i do, i want mi searchbar works, im doing an app, on IONIC VSCODE 
Here my

HTML HERE I WANT THE SEARCHBAR WORKS

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let interes of interesesObj">
<ion-label>{{interes.Nombre}}</ion-label>
<ion-checkbox slot="start" [(ngModel)] ="interes.isChecked"></ion-checkbox>
```

AND HERE THE SEARCHBAR

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-searchbar
  [(ngModel)]="miBuscador"
  [showCancelButton]="miStringDeCancell"
  (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<ion-searchbar  mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionClear)="setFilteredItems()"
      (ionChange)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Search Topic"></ion-searchbar>
```

In Ts

```
 getItems(query) {
  console.log(query)
  this.resetChanges();
  this.posts = this.filterItems(query.detail.value);
}



protected resetChanges = () => {
    this.posts = this.dummyPost;
  };


 setFilteredItems() {
    //console.log('clear')
    this.posts = [];
    this.posts = this.posts;
  }
  filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.posts.filter((item) => {
      return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });

  }
```